# r randomForest subset data NAs not being ignored

Tags: r, random-forest

I have original parent data I import through read.csv

```
all_data = read.csv(all_data_location, header=TRUE, sep = ',', colClasses= c(
  "trait1"=NULL,
  "trait2"="factor",
  "trait3"="double"
))
```

I can `randomforest(all_data[,target] ~., data = ae_data[,-target])` and life is good.

Now I want to create subset data using all_data.

```
subset_data = subset(all_data, all_data[,target] > 0)
```

But the new subset does not seem to preserve the column designations. This basically will give me NA errors: `randomforest(subset_data[,target] ~., data = subset_data[,-target])`

Is there a quick and convenient way for me to designate the columns again or to recycle them without typing all of the column titles over again?

Comment: It's hard to understand what is going on (at least for me) with the limited information provided, but my guess will be that the problem is column `trait2` which probably have empty levels and you need to refactor it again, something like `subset_data$trait2 <- factor(subset_data$trait2)`

Comment: So what's happening is that subset_data needs all its columns set again, instead of preserving "trait1"=NULL, "trait2"="factor", etc.

I was wondering if there was a more automatic way of doing it instead of spelling it out line by line, in case I create a bunch of subsets but want to make frequent changes to the parent (and have that pass to the subsets).

Comment: It is very strange what you saying. Why would it lose it's col classes?

Comment: I'm kinda confused as well to be honest.  If I have all_data's trait1=NULL (when it's, say full of integers), and then I subset it out, then subset_data's trait1 gets reverted back to integers.  So now I need to manually set subset_data's columns to the appropriate type.

Comment: What is `ae_data`? What is `target`? Have you gone through  `example(randomForest)`?  Also, you're missing a few parentheses.

Comment: Added parens (sorry, sloppy code transferring).  Have used randomForest libraries quite a bit and I can get my desired job done... I just want to do it more elegantly than doing a colClass specification over and over manually (I have 100+ columns).

Comment: I don't understand.  `randomForest` uses matrix algorithms, and therefore your column classes would be coerced to either character or numeric no matter what.  The column classes in a matrix must all be the same. The resulting frames are matrices as well, I believe.

Comment: In response to your final two lines, you could just assign the classes to a vector and recycle it.

Comment: Richard: So I have to NULL my column classes when they exceed 32 factors (a limitation of randomForest).  So based on the data I'm trying to maximize my columns used but on a first pass I NULL out certain columns that I can't use.

Assigning the classes to an assignable vector sounds like a good plan though.  Let me try implementing...